# @FormParam case sensitivity in Java Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am using Java with Jersey 1.16.

Is the name of a @FormParam parameter case sensitive? 
Can I somehow force it to be NON case sensitive? (hopefully in some global way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the requests:

```java
public class CaseFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry: request.getFormParameters().entrySet()) {
      request.getFormParameters().put(entry.getKey().toLowerCase(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return request;
  }

}
```

And update `web.xml` accordingly:

```
...
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>org.example.CaseFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like something that will work. but I am not sure If I will use this. I am having doubts about the whole Q - maybe the Q should be what is more commonly expected of parameter names - are they usually expected to be case sensitive or not?

Comment: The specification says that URLs should be treated as case sensitive: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html

Comment: Thank you.
So case sensitive it will remain.