# Implementing Case-Insensitivity in Jersey JAX-RS (Dropwizard)

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I am looking to enforce case-insensitivity in Jersey JAX-RS paths,query/form params. I understand that the specification enforces case sensitivity; however, like most API developers who are not members of Opus Dei, I find it absolutely futile to spend hours of debugging time dealing with the consequences of a query/form param being silently ignored because the user used "helloWorld" instead of "helloworld" and cannot figure out why the method is not working as expected. I also see no plausible downside of implementing case insensitivity, as I am not a masochistic psychopath and thus would never construct two separate functionalities for /tedcruzsexscandal and /tedCruzSexScandal. I have also never seen an example of such a thing in the real world (if there is something I am missing feel free to correct me).

It would be great if Jersey had simple @CaseSensitive/@CaseInsensitive annotations, which would completely eliminate this very,very common need - but sadly such annotation do not exist and [do not appear to be something with which the Jersey developers are concerned](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Case-Insensitive-QueryParams-td2459231.html). As a result, I am looking for the safest, least intrusive standard approach to implementing case insensitivity in Jersey for path/query/form without unintended consequences. As an example of a consequence that needs to be avoided, my past experiments with security filters have shown that manually processing the body containing the form parameters too early in a`ContainerRequestFilter` will break `@FormParam("paramName")` in downstream resources. Ensuring that the solution works with multipart forms and asynchronous http is critical as well.

If there is another Dropwizard compatible library that is similar to Jersey and has the necessary casing functionality, feel free to mention it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case-insensitive URLs with JAX-RS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624481/case-insensitive-urls-with-jax-rs)

Comment: @Meiko This question is more focused on a how to build a comprehensive solution for form/query/path params without breaking resources

Comment: query/path is part of the URL ... in my opinion the answer would be the same here.

Comment: Form params are diffrent though and a the acceped solution on that question doesn't really give any useful help other than suggestion to use a servlet filter which would break jaxrs resource methods by processing the body too early

Comment: ok, in my opinion the marked answer is the right answer :) 
here is the formparam answer... ok not jersey 2, but should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809342/formparam-case-sensitivity-in-java-jersey

Comment: That answer would break any method using @FormParam since the form would have already been consumed and thus basically negate the usefulness of JAX-RS - as you would essentially just write your webservices as a servlet filter at that point.

Comment: I cannot follow your argumentation "would break any method..." but I agree, this approach is not a good idea. Also I think, it is not a good idea to break with common internet standards... why should case insensitivity be useful? A != a ... like A != B ... but this is only my opinion... fact is, that your questions are already asked.

Comment: It's useful because if an end user of your API accidentally uses "helloworld" instead of "helloWorld" and the parameter is not required, the request will go through and the parameter will not be properly matched resulting in a potentially unexpected result. It is also likely that the user won't realize their simple mistake until after hours of debugging. Since no API developer would ever use "helloWorld" and "helloworld" as params in the same method, there is no downside to case insensitive matching- but there is an upside of saving several hours of debugging time for you/ your users.

Comment: Yes, a typo brings trouble sometimes. But the trouble would be the same, if he tries to write "helloword". And maybe, if you dislike camel case... why did you specify the path this way...

Comment: You are correct, but the difference is that I can't stop the user from making a typo, but I could (hopefully) eliminate the possibility of case errors by making lookups case insensitive. Sure it doesn't eliminate ALL potential user errors, but if it reduces the incidence by even 10 - 20% what technical reason is there not to do it? Also, I have had users expect this functionality in the past and just automatically assume something is wrong with the API when it doesn't perform case insensitive matching, so it is well worth it to me as there is no tangible downside to my knowledge.

Comment: I understand your problem, maybe the best argument is, that the internet is based on standards. We should follow what the holy W3C gives to us and so on ;) Your users could read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding (here related to mime application/x-www-form-urlencoded) the standard https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 is mentioned. But I would not blame you, if you prefer to avoid the discussion. Sometimes I am pragmatic too ;)

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
@Path("/{employees : (?i)employees}")
public class JerseyService
{
    //Code
}
```

[enter link description here](https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/case-insensitive-path-urls-with-jax-rs-jersey/)